# @jsonignore not working as expected in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

usercontroller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/listusersjson")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>> getListofUsersJson() {
        Iterable<User>   users = userService.listUser(); 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

user.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private int enabled;

    public User(Integer id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    public User() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Role> roless;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Cart> carts ;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails ;

}
```

Exception

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.addtocart.dto.User.roless, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.addtocart.dto.User["roles"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.addtocart.dto.User.roless, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.addtocart.dto.User["roles"])
```

Even though I have added the `@jsonignore` on all required fields where there is onetomany relationship and chances of lazyinitialization exception but still I am getting the above exception.I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution, but try `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` and just see what happens

Comment: If you want the lazy initialization to happen for associations, try transfer objects separately and copy them over for better control on user inputs and outputs. `@JsonIgnore` doesnt work on associations bounded to domain objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting `@JsonIgnore` on the getters instead of fields, e.g.

```
@JsonIgnore
public List<Cart> getCarts() {...}
```

Comment: Why is this even a thing, I expect that when I say ignore the field of a getter and setter that this is included as wel. But thanks this worked great.

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation you have two work arounds:

1- Eagerly fetching all relations:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

2- In lazy loading, just convert your DBO object to another bean and return it at response.

And @JsonIgnore is a method annotation as far as I know, try putting it on getters as @Predrag Maric mentioned

Answer (score 1):

There are two version of JsonIgnore.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
```

and

```
org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
```

the first one is right.